# Django template - how to access form in forms (context) given an index number (generated by an iterator)

Tags: django, django-templates, formset

I have two forms - a source form and a result form.

**Forms.py**

```
class SourceForm(forms.Form):
    some_source_field = forms.forms.CharField(...)

class ResultForm(forms.Form):
    some_result_field = forms.forms.CharField(...)
```

My view has uses `formset_factory` to render two instances of each and passes this to the template with a range of numbers that matches how many forms are to be rendered.

**Views.py**

```
class MyView(Vew):

    def get(self, request):

        forms_to_render = 2

        SourceFormSet = formset_factory(SourceForm, extra=forms_to_render)
        ResultFormSet = formset_factory(ResultForm, extra=forms_to_render)

        context = {
            'source_forms': SourceFormSet,
            'result_forms': ResultFormSet,
            'init': range(0, forms_to_render),
        }
```

In my template, I want to generate a container for which holds a source_form and result_form, for each of the numbers in the given range (2 in this case), as below.

**template.html**

```
{% for i in init %}
  <div class="container-fluid" id="primary_container_{{ i }}">
    {{ source_forms.i }}
    {{ result_forms.i }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

*Background: I have a javascript queue which unhides one `primary_container` at a time to be processed; I hide the "just-processed" container and populate it in the background while the user works on the next formset in the queue. The purpose is minimize the wait time while a form populates.*

If I hard-code the index value of 0 or 1 in, the form renders.

```
{{ source_forms.0 }} <!-- works fine -->
{{ source_forms.1 }} <!-- works fine -->
```

However, this doesn't work

```
{% for i in init %}
  {{ source_forms.i }} <!-- doesn't render form -->
{% endfor %}
```

I thought maybe `i` was no longer the correct data type, so I tried this, which also doesn't work

```
{% for i in init %}
  {% with forloop.counter0 as x %}
    {{ source_forms.x }} <!-- doesn't render form -->
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

I got it working by doing this:

```
{% for i in init %}
  {% for form in source_forms %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == i %}
      {{ form }} <!-- renders form -->
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But is there a simpler way to get the correct `form` in `forms` given the index `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django template engine *by design* does not let you do indexing.

The answer is to use a [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) to do indexing (or to use the Jinja template engine, which is a bit of a sledgehammer if this is the only nut to crack). This is one I wrote earlier, for indexing a dict-like entity.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def lookup( d, key): 
    """ filter: d is dict-like. return d[key] with '' as default using get method """
    return d.get( key, '')
```

Usage: `{{ dict_thing|lookup:key }}`

In your case I would somewhat expect the following to work:

```
@register.filter
def index( lst, index): 
    return lst[index]
```

Usage: `{{ source_forms|index:x }}`

Note: no whitepace allowed around the `|` or `:` in the template

Another way I have used in the past is to pass a generator function ( `yield result` ) in the context to the template, which you can then iterate over in the template using `{% for x in generator %}`  I think Python's `zip` may be all you need here:

```
return render( ... context={
   'formpairs': zip( SourceFormSet, ResultFormSet), ...
})
```

and in the template

```
{% for pair in formpairs %}
  <div class="container-fluid" id="primary_container_{{ forloop.counter }}">
  {{ pair.0 }}
  {{ pair.1 }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was like that by design. The `includes` option is great as I can reuse it. It works really well like this `{% with result_forms|index:i as result_form %}<form.../>{% endwith %}`

Comment: Yes, IMO it's the single most infuriating thing in the whole of Django. Easy work-around, but even if there are good reasons for the design, why not include a generalized lookup tag  in Django's standard template tags?

Comment: A similar issue I recently resolved was that {{ foo.bar}} failed to return `bar` if `foo` was a callable. Yet another custom tag needed.